NDIS packet monitoring using Volatility (IEEE 802.1x protocol)
Is it possible to parse IEEE 802.1x from Volatility, an advanced memory forensics framework in Python? Here's the link to the GitHub page: "https://github.com/volatilityfoundation/volatility?tab=readme-ov-file". And from there, how do I exactly catch this OID: OID_802_11_PMKID where I can cast _BSSID_INFO structs and get all MAC address and PMKID pairs? Here's the link to OID_802_11_PMKID: "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/network/ff559321(v=vs.85)".
I tried using driver_ndis.c from different driver implementations I found on the internet but I found many inconsistencies and incompatibilities. I'm using using Windows 10 and is it still possible to make WPA supplicants work so that I can easily set wireless configurations such as dhcp, dns, ssid and etc (.conf) and sniff or inject association, authentication, disassociation, deauthentication frames and etc.

If you can make Python code snippet using volatility library, I can give you a green check. I'll check on my end if it works.

Here on Stack Overflow it usually works the other way around: you are expected to post your code, as a minimal reproducible example demonstrating a specific problem and we check it.
